# dd will NOT recognise my sdcard ie "no such file or directory" it is seen by all other routes gparted,df,lsusb,blkid,,,so on

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, symbolic-link, sd-card

xubuntu 12.04-32 I am trying to build a bootable sdcard for my tablet and everything is ready but "dd" will NOT recognise any of my sdcard(s) 2Gb micro sd,8Gb or 32Gb

Comment: What's the command you're using and what's the error you get?

Comment: root@randy-laptop:/home/randy/u-boot-sunxi# dd if=/dev/zero of=$/dev/sdb1 bs=1M count=1
dd: opening `$/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory I have tried several diff ways to ident target ie /media/xxxxxxx-xx  and uuid no joy yet I can copy and paste to and from sdcard with "thunar" at will

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=$/dev/sdb1 bs=1M count=1
```

`/dev/sdb1` is a path, just like `/dev/zero`. You're using `$/dev/sdb1`, which should be just `/dev/sdb1`.

So you should use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M count=1
```

Also, this way you're only filling the first partition with zeros. If you you want to write zeros to the whole drive you should use `/dev/sdb` instead of  `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: Louis Matthijssen Yes I realised my error a little later thank you for responding